# Hyperledger Fabric: How to define new responsibilities for miners?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In Ethereum, we cannot define/add new responsibilities for miners unless we modify/change miners' code.

**Question**: In Hyperledger Fabric, can we define/add new responsibilities for/to miners by using system chaincodes? or the system chaincodes are only for certain purposes (e.g. defining policies, validation)?

---

edit: this edit is done after the 1st answer has been provided.

miner or nodes or peers or orderers

Answer (score 2):

There is no mining or miners in Hyperledger Fabric.

Comment: what about nodes/peers?

Comment: Peers maintain identical copies of a ledger by channel and chaincode. They may be endorsers or only committers. They have no other responsibilities, so there is little to change.

Comment: thanks for your comment,  but it doesn't answer my question. Imagine there is a complex crypto. protocol. My question is: What part of the protocol should be implemented in user chaincode and what part in system chaincode and why?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Jworthington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8195263/jworthington) stated, there are no miners in Hyperlegder. You need to take a step back and understand the core difference between Public Blockchains (Ethereum) and Permissioned Blockchain (Hyperledger, Corda).

To be fair, calling Hyperledger a blockchain is a bit of a misnomer. It is a distributed legder, and does not require the action of miners to reach consensus.

Both platforms work with the concept of nodes, with differing functionality. They are both similar in that nodes host versions of the `world state/ legder`. In ethereum , you have miner nodes, which are full nodes, with the additional responsibility of validating transactions via Proof of Work. In Hyperlegder, nodes function either as clients (to connect with the Fabric network), peers ( copies of the world state, validate or endorse transactions) and Orderer.

When you write chain code, you craft the rules that dictate the validation of transactions by the orderer. This is installed on peers and instantiated on each of the channels. You install the chain code on peers you want to endorse transactions (using the Lifecycle System Chaincode).

Endorsers simulate and endorse transactions using the Endorsement System Chaincode (ESCC), while committer peers validate transaction using the Validation System Chaincode (VSCC).

Hope this helps.